# Dynamic Array Type Error on making the list function

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

New to data structures and Algorithms trying out Dynamic Arrays

```
import ctypes

class DynamicArray(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.capacity = 1
        self.A = self.make_array(self.capacity)

    def __len__(self):

        return self.count

    def get(self, x):

        if not 0 <= x < self.count:
            return IndexError(f'Your value is {x} is out of bounds ')


        return self.A[x]


    def append(self, x):

        if self.count == self.capacity:

            self._resize(2 * self.capacity)

        self.A[self.count] = x
        self.count += 1


    def _resize(self, new_cap):

        B = self.make_array(new_cap)
        for i in range(self.count):
            B[x] = self.A[x]

        self.A = B
        self.capacity = new_cap


    def make_array(self):
        return (new_cap * ctypes.py_objects)()



arr = DynamicArray()

arr.append(1)
```

When I test run the code I get the error that

> ln8: self.A = sekf.make_array(self.capacity)  TypeError: make_array()
>   takes in 1 positional arguments and 2 were given

I do not understand because I only passed in one argument unless I am not understanding please help

Answer (score 0):

On the function

```
def make_array(self, new_cap):
         return (new_cap * ctypes.py_objects)()
```

The argument 'new_cap' was missing hence throwing the 1 argument error